# Proxychains & TOR ping

Tags: linux, proxy, tor

I'm trying to ping a host through TOR and Proxychains.

I have proxychains configured to work with TOR with:

```
socks4         127.0.0.1 9050
```

in `proxychains.conf` and I have TOR service running.

I then try
`proxychains ping google.com` and get this output:

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
PING google.co.uk (**.**.136.94) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from **.**.136.94: icmp_req=1 ttl=36 time=855 ms
64 bytes from **.**.136.94: icmp_req=2 ttl=36 time=72.5 ms
64 bytes from **.**.136.94: icmp_req=3 ttl=36 time=148 ms
```

showing that it's not going through TOR. For some reason only `proxychains iceweasel` seems to go through TOR. Everything else doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOR only supports TCP, not UDP or ICMP.